# SAP UI5: Enable Disable Fields Input based on Users

Tags: sapui5

I am working on SAP UI5 Application having a form. Form will be filled by 3 different users once submitted by initial user.

Requirement is to enable and disable input fields based on users. Please suggest best possible way to do this activity.

I know we can , enable disable fields using following code but its not based on user ids.

```html
<Input name="NameClient1" id="NameClient1_id" valueLiveUpdate="true" liveChange="_validateSaveEnablement" maxLength="100"
enabled="{= ${viewModel>/mode} === 'edit' || ${viewModel>/mode} === 'create' ? true: false}" visible="true" value="{ path: 'NameClient1', type: 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.String' }"/>
```

Comment: Logic should come from backend. There you have access to `sy-uname`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you to get the user info, store it in the local data model, then access it from the XML view.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please share some code, should i write it in controller or can be added in XML View.

Comment: Yes, I can, but can you please clarify on how you get the user info from the backend service? 
Are you using OData? If yes, what version do you use?
And yes, you should get the user info and store it in the model in controller